# Did you use the reactive mongodb driver with JDK14

Tags: mongodb, mongo-java-driver, reactive-streams, java-14

When trying to create a **com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.MongoClient** using:

```
MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017");
```

I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultClusterableServerFactory.<init>
```

I'm using **mongodb-driver-reactivestreams 4.1.0** dependency and **mongo-java-driver 3.12.6**

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're mixing versions that are not compatible. If you want to use `mongodb-driver-reactivestreams` 4.1.0, then any other MongoDB dependencies should also be version 4.1.0. If you only want (or need) the reactive driver, then just remove the `mongo-java-driver` dependency.

If you also need the non-reactive driver then you need to use either `mongodb-driver-sync` 4.1.0 or `mongodb-driver-legacy` 4.1.0; the `mongo-java-driver` dependency was discontinued in version 4.x. See also [Upgrading to the 4.0 Driver](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/4.2/upgrading/).